# How to get unanswered questions by tag on Stack Overflow app

Tags: discussion, android-app, search, unanswered-questions

I'm trying to figure out how to just get unanswered questions by a tag in the Stack Overflow app. Is it possible right now? If not can anyone give an ETA on when this is coming out?

Comment: Works.!! But also lists answered ones, any idea why?

Comment: No idea why, a bug maybe. I searched for an example and all it returned was questions with **no answers**.

Comment: Thought there wud be a direct way to search in app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure about the Android app, but with a web browser you can search

```
[your-tag] answers:0
```

which will return you with results that carry the tag [your-tag] **and** has no visible answers.

If you'd like to compete with existing answers, you can replace `answers:0` with `hasaccepted:no` so questions that has no accepted answers will also show up.

The search engine is the same across platforms (see quotation below) so you can try it on the Android app.

> **Update** The new search is now the default across the network.